# Wordpress get_avatar function not correct working

Tags: php, wordpress

My code doing this, listing which author have posted in the current category. But `get_avatar` function not correct working. Im Using Simple Local Avatar Plugin. It is working author.php don't have any problem. But when i use it my this code, it is listing same and wrong author picture(My latest author picture. [You can look this picture](http://www.screencast.com/t/O02Y5bOx4y0))

My Code:

```
<?php if (is_category()) {?>
<?php
$current_category = single_cat_title(“”, false);
$author_array = array();
$args = array(
'numberposts' => -1,
'category_name' => $current_category,
'orderby' => 'author',
'order' => 'ASC'
);
$cat_posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($cat_posts as $cat_post) :
if (!in_array($cat_post->post_author,$author_array)) {
$author_array[] = $cat_post->post_author;
}
endforeach;
foreach ($author_array as $author) :
$auth = get_userdata($author)->display_name;
$autid= get_userdata($author)->ID;
echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '32' );
echo "<a href='?author=";
echo $autid;
echo "'>";
echo $auth;
echo "</a>";
echo "<br />";
endforeach;
?>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Can, my friend, multi-posting is not encouraged, please choose one site and stick to it, check: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this `echo get_avatar( get_the_author_email(), '32' );` to `echo get_avatar( $autid, '32' );`

`get_the_author_email()` returns email of the author in the current `loop` of wordpress and not from your `foreach` loop.